# ASP.NET MVC Get a list of users with particular profile properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 1 and I have added a custom Profile class using the WebProfile Builder VS add-in (found here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebProfileBuilder/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=980).

On one of my forms I want a drop-down list of all users who share a specific profile value in common.

I can see that I can get a list of all users using:

```
Membership.GetAllUsers()
```

However I cannot see how to get all users who have a specific profile value, which in my case is CellId.

Am I approaching this in the right way?  I have used membership roles to define which users are administrators etc, but profiles seems like the right place to group users.

Any pointers both in specifics of how to access the user list but also comments on whether am I pursuing the right avenue here would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 3):

There is no query API for Profile, but this may give you some guidance:

```
var usersWithNonZeroCounter = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
    .Where(user => true /*insert your user criteria here*/)
    .Select(user => ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName, true))
    .Where(profile => ((int)profile["counter"]) > 0 /*insert your profile criteria here*/)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one comparison you can use following statement:

```
return Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
        .Where(user => ((int)ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName, true)["Owner"]) == _ownerid);
```

If you need more evaluations, why dont you use the *let* operator to store the profile in.